# Why a field is needed in a GROUP BY clause if I need it only for conditional in a WHEN clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to create a query to get results like this picture below.

One line per person.

[image]

The problem is that when I'm creating my query, fields that I'm only using them for WHEN CLAUSE (I don't even need to show them as results), it's showing up as an error asking to add them to the GROUP CLAUSE or AGGREGATE FUNCTIONS. And probably this is creating duplicated lines in my results for each user.

My query just runs if I put UserLogon, JobPageFormat and JobIsDuplex in the group clause.

The database I'm using is MS SQL Server 2008

Please see my sql query

```
select UserLogon, count(TrackingId) as Jobs,

case
when JobPageFormat = 'A3' then SUM(TrackingPageCount*2)
when JobPageFormat != 'A3' then SUM(TrackingPageCount) 
end as Total_Pages, 

case
when JobPageFormat = 'A3' then SUM(TrackingColorPageCount*2)
when JobPageFormat != 'A3' then SUM(TrackingColorPageCount)
end as Color_Pages,

case
when JobPageFormat = 'A3' then (SUM(TrackingPageCount*2) - SUM(TrackingColorPageCount*2))
when JobPageFormat != 'A3' then (SUM(TrackingPageCount) - SUM(TrackingColorPageCount))
end as Mono_Pages,

case
when JobPageFormat = 'A3' and JobIsDuplex = 0 then SUM(TrackingPageCount*2)
when JobPageFormat != 'A3' and JobIsDuplex = 0 then SUM(TrackingPageCount)
end as Simplex,

case
when JobPageFormat = 'A3' and JobIsDuplex = 1 then SUM(TrackingPageCount*2)
when JobPageFormat != 'A3' and JobIsDuplex = 1 then SUM(TrackingPageCount)
end as Duplex

from scTracking 

where ComputerName like '%ServerXXX%'
and JobType in (1,2,3)
and StartDateTime > '2019-09-01'
and StartDateTime < '2019-10-01'
group by UserLogon, JobPageFormat, JobIsDuplex
order by UserLogon
```

See the results I'm getting below

[image]

Does anyone knows how can I do this query without duplicating the results please?

Kind regards,
Luciano

Comment: Remove these two items: `JobPageFormat`, `JobIsDuplex` from your `GROUP BY` and add in the columns which you are using `SUM` on in the `GROUP BY`

Comment: Any field that gets aggregated needs to be in the `GROUP BY` clause. Agreed with @RyanWilson.

Comment: If you give some sample input and expected output you'll get a far better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your sums to be outside the case expression:

```
SUM(case
    when JobPageFormat = 'A3' then TrackingPageCount
    ELSE TrackingPageCount
    end) as Total_Pages, 
SUM(CASE WHEN JobIsDuplex = 0 
        THEN
        CASE when JobPageFormat = 'A3' then TrackingPageCount*2
        ELSE TrackingPageCount
    end) as Simplex,
etc.
```

then you can take `JobPageFormat` and `JobIsDuplex` out of the group by clause.

Comment: Just a note, that's a `case` _expression_, not statement.